# How to print pdf shipping labels on a laptop using zebra GC420D thermal printer?

Tags: pdf, zebra-printer

i'm planning to buy the zebra gc420d thermal printer. But i'm not sure if it can print shipping labels contained in a pdf file. Does the default zebra driver for GC420D thermal printer offer pdf printing feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about if the *driver* offers that feature, but rather is the PDF file formatted correctly.  If the PDF file is of the correct dimensions for your label printer, it should work fine.

Comment: Hi, please validate this link https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/ait/Printing-a-PDF-File-Using-the-ZDesigner-Driver.html

Comment: That link shows you how to reset the driver config.  Nothing to do with the PDF at all, other than that's the source of the print image.